# can I write a custom class loader to execute a static block before or while loading all the classes in a certain package in java 8?

Tags: java

I have a bunch of classes under a package that looks like this

```
package hello;

public class Foo1 {

  static {
     load();
  }

}

package hello;
public class Foo2 {

  static {
     load();
  }

}

package hello;
public class Foo3 {

  static {
     load();
  }

}
      .
      .  
      .  
      .  
      .  

package hello;
public class FooN {

  static {
     load();
  }

}
```

How can I factor out the common static block/initializer from all the classes under a certain package? can I write a custom class loader to execute a static block before or while loading all the classes in a certain package in java 8?

Comment: Writing a classloader for that seems a bit overkill. Why not moving the implementation of the static `load` into a separate class and delegate to that method from the static initialisation? This will not get rid of the static block in each class of your package, but avoids code duplication. Another approach would be inheritance or dependency injection, but your question gives not enough details to decide if that may be a valid approach.

Comment: if it doesn't help me get rid of the same static block in all the classes how does it avoid duplication?

Comment: If a classloader approach can help me avoid the same static block that would be great..I just need more pointers on that